# Routing issue on post between controller : Right page loaded but wrong URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

When I click on my first page submit button, the right destination page is displayed but with the wrong URL. It's still the URL of the first page : Indeed the htm page displayed is the right one : `topologieInstanceCouloir.html` but the url is http://localhost:8990/bus/topologie instead of `http://localhost:8990/bus/topologieInstanceCouloir`. That's why the `createForm` is not called. Do you have an idea of why that happens?

I have a list `allTypesCle` in a `modelAttribute` element which is not filled the first time I display my web page. But when I submit the form, using the `addCouloir` method the list is well filled and displayed.

I use Spring 4.2  through spring boot.

Here is the previous controller code, mainly the validform (submit method)  routing to the htm page where my issue is.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(value = "topologie", types = { Topologie.class })
@RequestMapping("/bus/topologie")
public class TopologieController {

    private static final String VIEW_TOPOLOGIE = "topologie";
    private static final String VIEW_TOPOLOGIE_INSTANCECOULOIR = "topologieInstanceCouloir";
...
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String createForm(
        @RequestParam(value = "fileTopo", required = false) String id,
        @ModelAttribute("topologie") Topologie topologie, Model model)
                throws Exception {

    if (topologie == null) {
        topologie = new Topologie();
    }

    if (id != null) {
        loadTopoFromFile(topologie, id);
        topologie.setIsPassageCvs(Boolean.TRUE);
        final List<String> allVersionCadre = getAllCadreVersion(topologie);
        final List<String> allNatures = getAllNatures(topologie);
        model.addAttribute("allVersionCadre", allVersionCadre);
        model.addAttribute("allNature", allNatures);
    }

    model.addAttribute("topologie", topologie);
    return VIEW_TOPOLOGIE;
}

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "definirInstance" })
    public String validForm(final Topologie topologie,
            final BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes attr,
            HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest req) {

        logger.info("REST request to valid form : {}", topologie);
        topologieService.update(topologie);

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            logger.info("Form has errors ! : {}", result);
            return VIEW_TOPOLOGIE;
        }

        attr.addFlashAttribute("topologie", topologie);
        return VIEW_TOPOLOGIE_INSTANCECOULOIR;
    }
```

here is the 2nd controller code :

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(value = "topologie", types = { Topologie.class })
@RequestMapping("/bus/topologieInstanceCouloir")
public class TopologieInstanceCouloirController {

private static final String VIEW_TOPOLOGIE_INSTANCECOULOIR = "topologieInstanceCouloir";

private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(TopologieInstanceCouloirController.class);

@ModelAttribute("allTypesCle")
public List<String> getAllTypesCle() {
    logger.info("ModelAttribute to get all types Cle");
    return typesCleService.getAll();
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String createForm(
        @ModelAttribute("topologie") Topologie topologie, Model model)
                throws Exception {

    if (topologie == null) {
        topologie = new Topologie();
    }
    model.addAttribute("topologie", topologie);

    return VIEW_TOPOLOGIE_INSTANCECOULOIR;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "addCouloir" })
public String addCouloir(@ModelAttribute("topologie") Topologie topologie,
        final Model model,
        final HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException {
    final String param = req.getParameter("addCouloir");
    logger.info("REST request to add Couloir : {}", param);

    return VIEW_TOPOLOGIE_INSTANCECOULOIR;
}
```

And here is the html code :

```
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/bus/topologieInstanceCouloir}"
        th:object="${topologie}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
...
    <div class="form-group" th:if="!${#lists.isEmpty(allTypesCle)}">
        <label for="typeCles" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Types
            de clé</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div th:each="typeCle : ${allTypesCle}" class="checkbox">
                <label th:for="${#ids.next('typesCle')}"> <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    th:field="*{partitions[__${rowPartitionStat.index}__].instances[__${rowInstanceStat.index}__].typesCle}"
                    th:value="${typeCle}" class="checkboxTypeCles" /> <span
                    th:text="${typeCle}">...</span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `if (topologie == null) { topologie = new Topologie(); }` does nothing outside your method, by the way. You'd be better off throwing NPE rather than creating a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you miss

```
model.add("topologie", topologie);
```

In your createForm method

UPDATE

Try to add also the code

```
@ModelAttribute("topologie")
public List<String> getAllTypesCle() {
    logger.info("ModelAttribute to get Topologie");
    return new Topologie();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but this modification, to be precise `model.addAttribute("topologie", topologie);`, doesn't change anything. The problem seems to be that the code in `createForm` and in `getAllTypesCle` is not executed before the .htm code.

Comment: For me it's not filled because the topologie is not added to the model. So it can't be accessed from view (html)

Comment: I think I haven't been clear : I've added the code in my createForm `model.addAttribute("topologie", topologie);`, I've edited my question so that you can see it now. But the rest of the topologie object is well displayed so I don't think it's the only problem : The fact that createForm is not executed seems, to me, to be the problem. But I can be wrong obviously!

Comment: To exclude guesses add some logs or set a breakpoint to debug to be sure it's called or not.

Comment: I'm sure it's not called because I've already added a breakpoint in `createForm` and another one in `getAllTypesCle`. it's not called before the first display (`Get`) whereas It's called when I submit the `addCouloir` action (`post`).

Comment: Then please describe how you call it

Comment: I thought it was implicit via the framework : the submit in the previous page controller directly goes to the Get method of the routed controller. A bit ambitious, I know now. How do I have to tell explicitly to execute the Get method of the `TopologieInstanceCouloirController`. I've added the code of the previous controller in my question. I use Spring 4.2  through spring boot.

Comment: When you call in browser something like localhost:8080/bus/topologieInstanceCouloir the createForm should be called returning name of view (html in your case) to display the URL. Then you fill data and submit it (POST is sent) and the addCouloir should be called now

Comment: Indeed the htm page displayed is the right one : `topologieInstanceCouloir.html`  but the url is `http://localhost:8990/bus/topologie` instead of `http://localhost:8990/bus/topologieInstanceCouloir `. That's why the `createForm` is not called. Do you have an idea of why that happens?

Comment: Your method listens /bus/topologieInstanceCouloir (according to specified request mapping). When you call another url it's not intercepted and the method is not called

Comment: I don't understand how the routing must be done. I've made a change which works : I change the validForm return with `return "redirect:/bus/" + VIEW_TOPOLOGIE_INSTANCECOULOIR;`. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: For me there should be 2 methods in controller e.g. with the same RequestMapping (e.g. /bus/topologie). One listens GET and ONE listens POST. When user clicks on page (GET) initial one is opened and you fill your model with default values. When user changes the data and submits the form (POST) you validate and return the same view as returned from GET in case of any errors.

Comment: That's what I have, I 've added the mothod listening to the GET in my question. But my question is : When the user submit the data and there is no error, how do I return the new view in a better way than the redirect. The reidrect is a trick but not a good one : It removes at least the back button possibility.

Comment: Redirect is usual way. It's good to remove back button. Back means resend submit data once more. Imaging you submit on create user. and then press back . Thus you try to create the same user once more.